# badrequest when sending json data

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I'm trying to send json data to an api and it doesn't come trough.

First of all the data is a list of objects. the very first time it works, and that is because the array is empty.

however the second time it tries to send I directly get a 400 without my debugger even coming in the controller.

I suspect that my json data cannot be deserialized form some reason, this is also my second suspect again since my reponse is of type application/problem+json.

However everything might be possible tough.
I have tried to use ['frombody'], I have tried build in json serializer aswell as newtonsoft. I have tried to use formatting.Intended but all witouth luck.

There is one paramater in my object a string that could cause problems as it contains  lot of special characters-> this paramater hold a fysical path to a directory so it will contains '/' and '' and space and or other special characters from the directory name.

client:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
                message.Content = JsonContent.Create(files, typeof(List<WatchedFile>));
                message.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5245/api/fileagent");
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                var response = await client.SendAsync(message);   
                
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    logger.LogError($"Sending to api was not successful {(int)response.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
```

This still needs to be refactored to inject the hhtpclient rather thatn the using statement

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddMessages([FromBody]List<WatchedFile> messages)
        {

            messages.ForEach(x => x.Ipaddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString());
            //send to repository                   
            await context.WatchedFiles.AddRangeAsync(messages);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the JSON is actually a valid JSON.

Then you try to send it with Postman to your endpoint to see if you get the intended result.

That would at least help you eliminate some of the places where it could go wrong.

Comment: Well I since i'm working with microservices, I actually made a 'common' class library and put my model there just to make sure both client and server use the same model, secondly for testing purposes I reduced the model to only use an id : guid, and timestamp: datetime, and yet exactly the same result